# Include GitHub project using link without downloading

Tags: github, cdn

I found a small GitHub project that I want to use (https://github.com/NewSignature/us-map) to create a clickable map. It is a jQuery plugin. I don't want to download it and clutter up my project though. Is there a way to link to the project in like a script tag and link tag?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you could use a CDN for this if the project offers one already.  You could ask the project if one exists, or see if common CDNs already offer it, and use that.  Otherwise, you'll need to host it yourself.

While GitHub does provide a way to view the raw contents of a file, it isn't intended as a CDN for you to use.  Raw files are not hosted directly, but instead generated from the repository, so for performance and availability reasons, GitHub doesn't want people to use it as a substitute for hosting their own dependencies.